# How do you search for specific apps installed on Android?

Tags: applications, search

How do you search for specific apps from installed apps on Android and the list them out? I need to search all apps installed on the device to check if three specific apps are among them. If yes, then I need to list all/any found installed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use free and open source  [AM Pre-release](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/io.github.muntashirakon.AppManager) app. You can search for any installed app by its name and package name. You can sort apps by label, package name, user apps, system apps, disabled, last update, etc. At first run the app would ask you to setup adb or grant root access. Simply deny it or skip the step. It is optional.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use another free and open source [Permissions Manager X](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.mirfatif.permissionmanagerx) app developed by a fellow member of our community, Irfan Latif. The app offers search by name, package name, permissions. You can also exclude apps based on user/system app type and type of permissions.

[image]